# DBMS table not found after building geometric network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, arcgis-10.4, geometric-network

I have created a geometric network within the Water dataset, accessing as GISadmin in SQLServer, in ArcGIS 10.4.1. It builds successfully and creates the desired line-and-point network for use in one version. However, the MXD for a different version with privileges to the same dataset shows red !'s in the ToC for each of the networked features. An attempt to set data source returns the error DBMS table not found.

That same version has properly functioning networks in other datasets with the same privileges. When I remove the water network, the layers fill properly in all versions.

What tables are being referenced in the DBMS error?